# Is it possible to do this in single query?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, the first table:

[image: Table1]

And here's the 2nd table:

[image: Table2]

Desired Output:

```
Jan |  1,000,000
Feb |   0.000
Mar |   0.000
```

is it possible with single query ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Using `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Faytraneozter No need of joins...

Comment: but desired output? i don't think it's possible. Please have a look to the sales?

Comment: I think `select sum(sales) from table where month(date) = 1` would do it, or do you need that other table? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: There is no way your tables displayed will give you that output. Unless you want to explain it more as being the sum/100?

Comment: @Anant sorry, thats why im asking if this is possible with single query.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, i nid the result to show in 2nd table. like Jan | 1,000,000.00

Comment: @edward I already edited my desired output. What im try to say is this, I want to sum all the value from table1 and show result to table2 depends on which date ( range ) has the value.

Comment: You can display a month name in PHP pretty easily. Why is the second table needed?

Comment: So take chris85's query and stick an insert into table 2 Infront of it, probably inside a loop to get all months, if you're not worried about years. Adding as well that I believe best practice would be having both sales columns as same type; choose int or decimal

Comment: @chris85 Actually im using google chart and all the data are stored inside table2. Thats why i need the second table so everytime there's an input inside "SALES" column from table1 it will automatically reflect the result to second table.

Comment: Please first explain what is the relation between `table1` and `table2`. Is there any relation between Sales fields?

Comment: @edward Thanks for the advice

Comment: @EhsanT theres no common key between the 2 table.

Comment: Then please explain in what logic do you desire the output you provided, I mean in your desired output you have 2 fields(1- Month name, 2- Sales) which of these fields should come from which table?

Comment: Not familiar with Google chats but wouldn't that be more like Excel than mySQL? In which case you need completely different syntex.

Comment: @EhsanT I want to Sum all the value from "Sales" which is from table1 and reflect the result to table2 but depends on date ( range ) like from "Jan 01-31" it will fall under "Jan" on table2.

Comment: So why do you need table2 at all?!

Comment: @edward Same here. its my first time to use google chart thats why im trying to ask for single query if possible. So i wont having hard time retrieving data and pass it on chart.

Comment: @EhsanT like what i said, its my first time to use google chart and I think having all data in one table is much easier to retrieve and pass the value to chart.

Comment: I think you need to research how Google charts works. Google won't care what your DB is structured like. It is only displaying the data provided.

Comment: I still do not get it. Please correct my if I'm wrong, it seems that all the data you need is in table1, So again my question is why do you need table2?

Comment: @ehsant yes all the data that i need is from table1, the purpose of having second table is for me retrieve all the data easier since im not familiar with the google chart and it also serves as Summary of all the sales from table1

Comment: But it's not, If it was, then in table 2 `Sales` field for "January" you should have 1,000,000 not 0.0000

Comment: I mean why you only not use this query: select month(`Date`) as month_no, date_format(`Date`, '%b') as month_name, sum(`Sales`)
from table1
group by month_name, month_no
order by month_no ?

Comment: @ehsant Wow it also worked but it only gives 'JAN' Month and sorry im not aware that i can get that without 2nd table. Thanks sir!

Comment: :) You are welcome, but what do you mean it only gives "JAN"? This query will produce 12 records for 12 months, If you have the records for all months in table1. Otherwise only the months which have related records will be in the result. If you want to have all months even those which do not have related record, then U think you either should use `MySQL Stored Procedures` or calculate it in php, I think that is not achievable with only 1 query(at least with my knowledge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t2.`month`,
    SUM(t1.sales) as sales
FROM
    table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t2.`month` = DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, "%b")
GROUP BY t2.`month`
ORDER BY sales desc
```

Hope this helps you.

But For this you have to make a little bit changes like in your table Your month name should be of 3 characters only , because we are joining the table name by the month name and as you can see in table there is a date added so we will convert it to the other format with 3 characters name using `DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, "%b")` , so it's gonna work for you

In case you dont want to use the 2nd table try this

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, "%b") AS MONTH, SUM(t1.sales) FROM table1 AS t1 GROUP BY t1.date`

Comment: WOW thanks a lot sir! It worked for me, but why is the Month are not in right position ?

Comment: yeah i am trying to sort it, will update my query once i will be done

Comment: No need to try, just check my last comment please!

Comment: @EhsanT in my table i did not added a primary key for the 2nd table . that is why i got the problem. If i add it and use the order by key ASC  it will work

Comment: As I was trying to understand the logic of @Newbie I still think there is no need for table2 and thus, there is no need for join at all. But if you want to join, you also have to add another field to your select which is month number and then sort the result by month number...

Comment: @EhsanT Yess.. All he wanted to get is the Month name and Total sales for that Day. 
He could use `SELECT
 DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, "%b") AS MONTH,
 SUM(t1.sales)
FROM
 table1 AS t1
GROUP BY
 t1.date`

Comment: For **EhSanT** Thanks sir and sorry if i provide not enough information about my table and im not also aware that i can get the answer without 2nd table  

For **Punit Gajjar** Thanks also to you sir for providing the exact output that i want maybe i will modify my table and add ID so i can easily ASC according to ID.

 but again both of you're codes actually works for me.
Thanks to both of you!!

Comment: Glad to Help... Happy Coding  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.Month, SUM(f.Sales)
FROM firstTable f, secondTable s
GROUP BY MONTH (Date)
```

should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response but It didnt show the ouput that i want. it only sum all the value inside Sales column and repeat all the month.